# How to find the max values of each columns using a single SQL query

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a table, I want to get all the max values of col1, col2, col3 using one query only. I'm using sqlite and flask-sqlalchemy.

```
    | id | col1 |col2 |col3
    | -------- | -------------- |-------------- |--------------|
    | 1        | 1              | 88            |26            |
    | 2        | 2              | 17            |30            |
    | 3        | 5              | 9             |75            |
    | 4        | 93             | 2             |53            |
```

I tried

```
SELECT MAX(col1, col2, col3) FROM table
```

but then I got [(88,), (30,), (75,), (93,)]

I want the output to be

[(93,), (88,), (75,)]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want three separate calls to `MAX` here:

```sql
SELECT MAX(col1), MAX(col2), MAX(col3)
FROM yourTable;
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i'm looking for.